# PHP public readonly properties vs private field with getter

Tags: php, php-8.1

PHP 8.1 introduces [`readonly`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#language.oop5.properties.readonly-properties) class properties. For example, before I would write:

```php
class User
{
    public string $name;

    public function __construct(string $name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public getName(): string {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

But now I can do:

```php
class User
{
    public function __construct(
        public readonly string $name,
    ) {}
}
```

The latter is obviously much more compact, so I am wondering if this syntax completely replaces the former for every use case, or are there still cases where the "old" syntax should be preferred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One advantage of the "old" way is that you can choose different access levels for the getter and setter, whereas a `readonly` field has only a single access level. E.g. when you want your setter to be `protected`.

Another advantage of using getters is that it allows you to change the implementation without changing the class interface.

Furthermore `readonly` properties as the name suggests can be set only once very much like JavaScript `const` variables. Depending on context this might be a desirable or a bad thing. Certain properties should be only set once and attempts to set them again should be flagged.

Although being "syntax candy" `public readonly` properties do have [their merit](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/readonly_properties).